# A basis of the weight space in the semi-invariant ring corresponding to the weight $\langle(2,3,2),\cdot\rangle$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, invariant-theory, quivers

I'm trying to understand Example 10.11.1 on page 225 of the book *"An introduction to quiver representations"* by Harm Derksen and Jerzy Weyman (see the attached screenshot below)

[image]

I want to understand the line underlined in red.

> How does the choice of vectors $(\lambda,\mu,\nu)$ being $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ give us a basis for the weight space $\mathrm{SI}(Q,\beta)_{\langle(2,3,2),\cdot\rangle}$?

They are basically saying that the Schofield semi-invariants $c^{V}$ that you get by choosing these three vectors form a basis for the weight space $\mathrm{SI}(Q,\beta)_{\langle(2,3,2),\cdot\rangle}$ in the semi-invariant ring. This is the fact that I don't understand.